# Best Data Structure for storing and searching elements with multiple fields in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, hashset

Performance is always an important challenge.

I am developing piece of code in order to build a language model.

I have a corpus with so many sentences. I need to store the words of this corpus in a data structure and find following statistics whenever I need to calculate probabilities:
for example:

- I need to know the count of a specific word in the corpus. (how many times does a word exist in the corpus?)
- I need to know the count of the pair of two words. lets say there are two words named W1 and W2. I need to know how many times the combination of `W1 w2` exist in the corpus and the same for three words `W1 W2 W3`

currently I`m using the following data structure for storing the words:

```
private class WordList {
    public String word = "";
    public int count = 0;
    public WordList(String _word, int _count) {
        word = _word;
        count = _count;
    }
}
```

and for the pair of two words I store all the pairs:

```
private class bi_WordList {

    public String bi_word_1 = "";
    public String bi_word_2 = "";
    public int bi_count = 0;

    public bi_WordList(String _word_1, String _word_2, int _count) {
        bi_word_1 = _word_1;
        bi_word_2 = _word_2;
        bi_count = _count;
    }
}
```

I run my program and I get the correct answers. but the execution time is terrible!
my question is this: based on the condition that I already described, what is the best data structure for doing such a work? I heard about `Hashset` and that searching cost in `Hashset` is `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`; however, I do not exactly know how to use it.

Comment: `I do not exactly know how to use it.I do not exactly know how to use it.` What is that mean ?

Comment: I mean I have a word, I want a field for the word itself and a field of type integer for keeping the count of the word. the same for storing w1 and w2 and the count of 'w1 w2'. how to insert an element with multiple fields of different types into the hashset? and then search for finding the element and read the values of that specific element fields?